# Connect controls in Visual Studio 2010 UML Modeling Diagrams

Tags: visual-studio, uml, modeling, diagrams

I've tried to create UML diagram with MSVS 2010 b2 today and I've faced a problem.
After I added controls from toolbox (such as Class, Interface) I could not connect these items! 
So connecting controls have been disabled on the toolbox when I tried to drag it on working area.

How to connect UML controls?

thx

Answer (score 1):

You can connect shapes as described here: [How to: Edit a UML Model and Diagrams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409405%28VS.100%29.aspx#Drawing)

Basically, click the connector in the Toolbox, the source shape, and then the target shape. You can also right-click the source shape, click **Add**, and then the connector you want.

If this does not work, please use the following steps to file a bug through Microsoft Connect: [How to submit feedback on Microsoft Connect](http://bit.ly/chQycB)

You might also want to try the RC version, which has fixed many issues: [Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate RC](http://bit.ly/a6GKRR)